# Powershell: Toggling script variables using function

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I have a menu with default values. By selecting a menu item I want the value of the menu item to toggle. My toggle function was not working because I failed to set a global variable so I used a few examples found on SO and was able to toggle a preset value. Now, I find I'm unable to pass the default option variable to the toggle function and have it set. Please advise. Thanks.

```
#toggle test

$optionYes="Yes"
$optionNo="No"

echo "$optionYes, $optionNo"

function toggle($option) {
    if ($option -eq "Yes") { $global:option="No" }
    elseif ($option -eq "No") { $global:option="Yes" } }

toggle $optionYes
toggle $optionNo

echo "$optionYes, $optionNo"
```

---

```
$defaultExcel = "Yes"
function toggleOption($defaultOption) {
    if ($defaultOption -eq "Yes") {
        $global:defaultOption = "No"
    } elseif ($defaultOption -eq "No") {
        $global:defaultOption = "Yes"
    }
    $redrawMenu
}

function displayMenu() {
    echo "1) Excel [$defaultExcel]"
    echo "[1] to toggle option"
}

function runMenu() {
    do {
        displayMenu
        $choice=(Read-Host "Option")
        switch ($choice) {
            '1' {toggleOption $defaultExcel; runMenu}
            'Q' {exit}
        }
    } until ($choice -eq "Q")
}
runMenu
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to accomplish.  It looks like you might be masking your variables.

Comment: Apologies. Had to cut down to size. Menu shows default option. User selects option. Toggles value of default option.

`$defaultExcel="Yes"
function toggleOption($defaultOption){
if ($defaultOption -eq "Yes") {$global:defaultOption="No"}
elseif ($defaultOption -eq "No") {$global:defaultOption="Yes"}
$redrawMenu}
function displayMenu(){
echo "1) Excel [$defaultExcel]"
echo "[1] to toggle option"}
function runMenu(){
do {
displayMenu
$choice=(Read-Host "Option")
switch ($choice) {
'1' {toggleOption $defaultExcel; runMenu}
'Q' {exit}}}
until ($choice -eq "Q")}
runMenu`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out how to insert \n when pasting that damned code in. Basically, the user sees the default value of a option in a menu. By selecting a number the `toggleOption` is called like `toggleOption $defaultExcel` and the value is _supposed_ to be passed to `toggleOption`. Should be toggled yes/no and then rewritten to the global variable which is then called by a recursive rerun of the `runMenu` function. I believe the `$global:defaultOption="foo"` is writing to `$defaultOption` and not `$defaultExcel`. I was hoping to use a `toggleOption` function for many variables.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables make code confusing.  Generating global variables from *functions* make code unmaintainable.  I'd suggest having a return value from your function that then gets stored into the variable you need:

```
function Set-Option {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('Yes', 'No')]
        [string] $Option
    )

    if ($Option -eq 'Yes') {
        'No'
    } else {
        'Yes'
    }
}
```

In use:

```
'1' { $global:DefaultOption = Set-Option $defaultExcel; runMenu }
```

Comment: I had to change the `$defaultExcel="Yes"` to `$global:defaultExcel="Yes"`, but it's now working. Thanks so much, @TheIncorrigible1